# Vaadin layout for Java EE - Button positioning

Tags: java, vaadin

I am building a web application and I am using Vaadin for the front-end. I am currently creating a user interface where I have a textfield and a button. This textfield should be to the left of the button however it shows up on top of the button. Could anybody help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please take some time to familiarise yourself by taking the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading the [how to ask a good question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In its current form, the question provides little information to work with so it's pretty much unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the horizontal layout in which both of those components are was not set to the correct width. Silly mistake.

Comment: You should have your HorizontalLayout in undefined size, so it calculates how much space needs and reshapes accordly. Unless you want to fill al space horizontally.